# Code are not executed after a function call in C++

Tags: c++

All the codes are running fine, but after making a function call that takes two vectors, the codes which are written after the function is not running, compiler is not even throwing any error.

```
void fun(vector<int> nums1, int m, vector<int> nums2, int n){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i<m or j<n){
        if(nums1[i] > nums2[j]){
            int temp = nums1[i];
            nums1[i] = nums2[j];
            nums2[j] = temp;
            i++; 
        }
        else if(nums1[i]<=nums2[j]) i++;
    }

    while(j<n){
        nums1.push_back(nums2[j]);
        j++;
    }
    
   
}
```

After this function, no other function is running.

```
    vector<int> nums1;
    vector<int> nums2;
    int m; cin>>m;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        nums1.push_back(k);
    }
    int n; cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        nums2.push_back(k);
    }
   

    fun(nums1,m,nums2,n);
    

    cout<<"last"<<endl;
```

I am not getting the last code output.

Comment: `j` never changes in the loop, so `j < n` will always be true.  And therefore `i<m or j<n` will always be true.

Comment: Ask yourself: With the `while(i<m or j<n)` loop, when would `j` ever be more then `n`.

Comment: *"All the codes are running fine, but [...] the codes which are written after the function is not running"* -- which is it? The code after the function falls under "all the codes", so you are claiming that the code after the function is both "running fine" and "not running". When part of your code is not working, don't be in such a rush to defend your code. You are here to get help. Be upfront about your issue, as in *"My code is not running fine. After making a function call, the rest of the code does not run. I am not getting `"last"` output in the following code."*

Comment: Presumably one of the `i++` was supposed to be `j++` and the `or` is supposed to be `and` (but it's tough to be sure since we don't know what this function is supposed to do). Posting a link to [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and voting to close as a typo whose resolution is unlikely to benefit future readers.

Comment: [OT]: You don't have to provide size of vector separately, `num1.size()` would be enough.